# unable to extract images from bag file

Tags: rosbag, stereo, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data
I am following this tutorial.
after I did roslaunch export.launch,

```
"" [rosbag-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/krish/.ros/log/2e6402e2-2086-11e5-8d8c-0026c72b65a2/rosbag-2*.log"""
```

this is the message i got
I did ctrl+c
moved this file into test directory.
but I can;t see any images here

Also, i actually want to extract stereo images.
when I do rosbag info, I get:

```
types:       sensor_msgs/Image [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
topics:      /rrc_camera/left/image_raw    171 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
             /rrc_camera/right/image_raw   171 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212727/unable-to-extract-images-from-bag-file/) by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-03**:
Well, actually everything seems okay so far.
I assume you have adjusted the launch file accordingly?
I.e. set the bagfile name in line 2 of the launch file as well as remapped the topic in line 4?

Also, to get both images, you have to run it twice, once for left and once for right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several ways to do this, and the best and the simplest one is to write your own package for this, as per your requirement;
Here you need two exactly synchronized images at any given moment so subscribe to both the topics using [msg_filter](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters)  (see the section 7.2). once you are in call-back function convert both the images to cv::Mat and save them using imwrite("filenam",cv::Mat var) function. this way you can be sure about their time stamp.

another way is, using image_view package which comes with image_pipeline.

> > rosrun image_view extract_images _sec_per_frame:=0.01 image:=(image_topic_name)  [tLink](https://coderwall.com/p/qewf6g/how-to-extract-images-from-a-rosbag-file-and-convert-them-to-video)

you will have to run this package for both the topics separately, but be sure that both the time you get same number of images (in your case 171 images). (otherwise they arent stereo-images). one issue here is, this package save the images in jpg format which can have some data loss due to jpg compression.

---

Originally posted by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) with karma: 460 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-03**:
rosrun image_view extract_images _sec_per_frame:=0.01 image:=rrc_camera/left/image_raw
but, it displayed:
"""[ INFO] [1435930468.661967546]: Initialized sec per frame to 0.010000"""
and then, nothing is happening

**Comment by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) on 2015-07-03**:
run >> rosbag play bagfile.bag  in another terminal window